# cannot load/create TDS 2015/2017 ("cannot be opened because its project type .scproj")

Tags: tds

After installing TDS, neither can we open an existing .scproj nor create a new project
 "cannot be opened because its project type .scproj" is the error I get on VS2015 and on VS2017.

TDS-2015 installed with 2015
TDS-2017 installed with 2017.

Both does not work. ie, 1) cannot load exisitng project. 2) cannot create now TDS project.

The original solution was developed on VS2015 with TDS 5.5.0.20 (this version only has 2015 VS). So I tried this on 2015. and it does not work either.

Comment: What exactly have you installed? Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: TDS works only with VS.(not with Rider, not with SharpDevelop)
Make sure that you have installed TDS for VS that you are using.
TDS 2015 should be used with VS 2015. TDR 2017 should be used with VS 2017.

Comment: @Anton is there a TDS available that works with Rider and SharpDevelop?

Comment: @BlueClouds No, there is no Hedgehog TDS for Rider or SharpDevelop.

Comment: put on hold.. nice!